# PHP parse error and error code spilling into other pages

Tags: authentication, mysqli, php

ok im getting this parse error on my on my `login.php` page. It seems the code isn't taking into account to check if the user is already logged in. I have a file called `pagechecker.php` on each page that checks if there logged in but all its showing is php code on top of each page.

Error on `login.php` is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\OTLCoding\PHP\login.php on line 21

base.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbname = "login";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "DirectedStudies2012";

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);


?>
```

login.php

```
    <?php 
 include ("base.php");
 include ("passwordchecker.php");
 include ("functions.php");
include("pagechecker.php");


    function postInput($htmlName)
    {
    if(isset($_POST[$htmlName]))
    {
    return $_POST[$htmlName];
    }
    return null;
    }

    //check if the user is already login.
            if(isset($_SESSION['userid']))
            {
                //check the database for existing user.
                $usercheck->$mysqli->("SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid = ?");
                $usercheck->bind_param("i",$_SESSION['userid']);
                $usercheck->execute();
                $usercheck->store_result();
                $results = $usercheck->num_rows;
                if($results == 1)
                {
                    redirect("languages.php");
                }
            }

    $loginusername = postInput('username');
    $loginpassword = postInput('password');



    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        if($loginusername == "" || $loginpassword == "")
        {
            $error = "Please Enter your user name and password";

        }
        else
        {
                //user isnt logged in
                if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT userid, password FROM user WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1"))
                {
                    $stmt->bind_param("s",$loginusername);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->bind_result($userid,$correctHash);
                    $stmt->fetch();
                    if(ValidatePassword($loginpassword,$correctHash))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
                        redirect('languages.php')
                    }
                    $stmt->close();
                }
            }
        }
    }



?>
```

pagechecker.php

```
//used to check for already login.
    if(!isset($_SESSION['userid']))
    {
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
    else
    {
        $usercheck->$mysqli->("SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid = ?")
        $usercheck->bind_param("i",$_SESSION['userid']);
        $usercheck->execute();
        $usercheck->store_result();
        $results = $usercheck->num_rows;
        if($results == 0)
        {
          header("Location: login.php");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is located here:

```
...->$mysqli->(...
```

You should call it like that:

```
...->$mysqli(...
```

or like that:

```
...->mysqli(...
```

depending whether `$mysqli` is set or not.

Explanation is simple. You can call something like ([see more on this in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)):

```
$my_object->$my_variable_property_name('some argument');
```

but calling the arrow between property name and bracket is in fact a syntax error.

Comment: now its saying e in Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\OTLCoding\PHP\pagechecker.php on line 9

Comment: @JjHarris: Ok, what did you replace with what?

Comment: new error now after i fixed all errors its saying my page has too many redirect loops

Comment: This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at http://localhost//otlcoding/PHP/login.php has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Comment: If languages.php includes the login checker... it's redirection from languages.php to languages.php

Comment: @JjHarris: Then you now have something unrelated to the previous error. It looks like the script has many issues in it, you could possibly follow some good coding standards. Remove the last PHP closing tag (`?>`), if there is nothing to display in this script, increase the readability, separate presentation from application, and possibly use some good PHP framework to speed up the development. These are general advices, your original problem seems to be fixed now.

Comment: so do which redirect needs changed?

Comment: @JjHarris: This is completely unrelated to the original question, but consider one situation: what if `$_SESSION['userid']` is not set? In that case you will have constant redirection, because the request will first load `base.php` (which starts session and sets database settings), then load `pagechecker.php`, which will find that `$_SESSION['userid']` is not set, then will **immediately** redirect the request to the same page. Then it will **repeat the whole process from the beginning**, without any chance to get out of the loop unless the browser stops redirections and shows you the error.

Comment: all this is suppose to do is check to make sure the user is logged in to view all pages but register and login and index.php. They need to be a member to view those pages. I just dont see how the redirects are a issue

Comment: @Tadeck What's a good way to fix this. I am very new to php

Comment: @JjHarris: It is an infinite loop of redirects - if anyone goes to `login.php` without having `$_SESSION['userid']` set, will fall into infinite redirects that will be terminated by the browser. Do you see this issue or not? You need to perform some other check and allow user to finally view `login.php` page without being redirected (this is why you created that page, don't you? so why are you redirecting from it? it is counter-logical).

Answer (score 1):

Missing semicolon here:

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
redirect('languages.php')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $usercheck->$mysqli->("SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid = ?");
               ^----
```

This should probably be

```
   $usercheck->mysqli->etc....
```

Comment: that wouldn't result in a parse error.

Comment: it would be an "unset variable $mysqli" error.

Comment: do I know though because my base has $mysqli declared as mysqli

Comment: my bad, I didn't see *arrow bracket* typo even though you pointed it out, scumbag brain... so correction, it *would* create a parse error